# PHP: cURL w/ CSRF token

Tags: php, curl, csrf

N.B: I have viewed [Login with PHP curl and CSRF token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054825/login-with-php-curl-and-csrf-token) and [cURL CSRF Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785578/curl-csrf-token), [Login with CURL php and CSRF token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798948/login-with-curl-php-and-csrf-token) and then some before posting.

I am creating a system which has a function (if it works) to analyse data from another website. This website requires login with a user, password & csrf token. See below for the code.

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  if (curl_errno($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($response);
  $token = $doc->getElementsByTagName("csrf")->attributes->getNamedItem("value")->value[0];



    echo "TOKEN: {$token} ";
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

  $params = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'csrf' => $token
  );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));

  curl_exec($ch);

  if (curl_errno($ch)) print curl_error($ch);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    print("<br />HTML: ".$html);
if (curl_errno($ch)) print curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I have slightly modified scripts from the above questions but am receiving these errors:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in
>   Entity, line: 24 in
>   /home/dlip/subdomains$/eportaltest.website.com/public_html/ticket_load.php
>   on line 18
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : form in Entity,
>   line: 76 in
>   /home/dlip/subdomains$/eportaltest.website.com/public_html/ticket_load.php
>   on line 18
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag nav invalid in Entity, line: 124
>   in
>   /home/dlip/subdomains$/eportaltest.website.com/public_html/ticket_load.php
>   on line 18
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag section invalid in Entity, line:
>   140 in
>   /home/dlip/subdomains$/eportaltest.website.com/public_html/ticket_load.php
>   on line 18
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): error parsing attribute name in
>   Entity, line: 176 in
>   /home/dlip/subdomains$/eportaltest.website.com/public_html/ticket_load.php
>   on line 18

Following instructions on the above questions, I've tried also using

```
$doc->loadHTML(htmlentities($response))
```

to no avail.

Does anyone have any clue whats going wrong? I understand it may be to do with the website, but how do I get around it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you get the csrf token? Reason you see these warnings is that the site you try to parse has invalid HTML.

Comment: Nope. Do you think it would just be easier to explode the page and just take the bit I need in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a dirty answer but it works so that's ok with me...

Used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21804537/7508539

And rolled it like so:

```
  $token = trim(get_string_between($response,'<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="','" />'));
```

Will probably have to explode the bits I need on their site now, but at least I know how to tackle it now rather than sitting staring aimlessly at errors I can't fix.

Are there any 'non-hack' ways of fixing this?